# Multiple projects sharing same code without circular reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, f#

I have a C# and F# project. Both are supposed to be a service layer code. But sometimes, code from both project need to access code in the other project.

Can each project reference the other without any problems?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have circular assembly references. This will require refactoring the parts used by both assemblies into a third assembly, which can then be referenced from both.

Comment: Good answer. Just to add to this; This is not an F# specific problem. You'd have the same problem if both assemblies were in C# or VB or whatever.

Comment: If you could have F# code in a C# project, or C# code in an F# project, what would the purpose of different project types be? You could get by with one project type if that were possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create 3d project where you must add references from both and then you can use methods and objects from C# and F# projects together.

But usually you don't need such cross-reference. That must be an architecture problem.